# xml : how to reference a .xsd file at .xml file?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to see xml file in browser as I define in .xsd file. Please check the following two files for me and point out what do I need to do. These two files are under same folder.

employee.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>

<employee xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="employee.xsd">

  <firstname>John</firstname>
  <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</employee>
```

employee.xsd

```
<xs:element name="employee">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" fixed="red" />
      <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You made two errors: one in the schema file and another in the syntax of the value of the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute of the XML file.

The main error is that your employee.xsd file is only a fragment of the XML Schema. You should complete the contain of the employee.xsd. For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com/RedsDevils"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/RedsDevils employee.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="employee">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string" fixed="red" />
                <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and employee.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<employee xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/RedsDevils"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com/RedsDevils employee.xsd">

    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Smith</lastname>
</employee>
```

Because you define default namespace in the XML file, the schema location attribule `xsi:schemaLocation` must consist from the the namespace and the path to the schema devided with the blank. I changed the namespace name so that it will be a little more unique: `"http://www.w3schools.com/RedsDevils"` instead of `"http://www.w3schools.com"`.

At the end I can add that the XML file employee.xml not corresponds to the schema employee.xsd because the element `<firstname>John</firstname>` has the value other as `red`, but probably exactly this you wanted to test.

Comment: @Oleg Is it possible to specify that "every <employee> in this xml should follow the same schema?" rather than requiring xsi:schemaLocation in every <employee> tag?

Comment: @DavidDoria: By specifying of the XML Schema of `<employee>` we set schema for all it's children (for example `<firstname>` or `<lastname>`). Typically one set `xmlns` and `schemaLocation` for the **root** element of the XML file only. The example in my answer is very short. Typically one would have `<employees>` for example as root element with many `<employee>` children. In the way one would define one schema for every `<employee>` and specify additionally where `<employee>` could be placed inside of the root `<employees>` element.